# Convert character to Integer while leaving encoded

Tags: bluetooth, variables, convert

I have two characters, that I get by Bluetooth.

```
char a = SerialBT.read();
char b = SerialBT.read();
```

According to the [Arduino Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/char/), decoded data stored in a char gets encoded to ASCII text.
I want to combine them in an Intenger, but the following methods don't work:

```
int c = a + b;
```

```
int c = (int)a + (int)b;
```

```
int c = (a - 48) + (b - 48);
```

and

```
String c;
c.setCharAt(0, a);
c.setCharAt(1, b);
```

Thank you

Comment: The sentence “_decoded data stored in a char gets encoded to ASCII text_” makes no sense: `a` and `b` contain the received data _as is_, with no encoding/decoding whatsoever applied. All the methods you show _should work_, but do different things. What exactly are you trying to achieve by “combining” the characters? Please, show an example of the data you have and the result you want.

Comment: @Edgar Bonet, first thank you for the answer. Here is the example: I get the decimal numbers 49 and 50. I save them to two seperate characters, a and b. Now I want to make one number (c) out of two characters (a and b). When I try the methods shown in my post, it don't work.

Comment: What do you mean by “_it don't work_”? What numeric value would you expect `c` to have?

Comment: I expect it to be in ASCII value.

Comment: "What do you mean by “it don't work”?" - I get a decimal value, not a ASCII one. Sorry, I didn't write it clearly.

Comment: The ASCII value of what? Please, answer my question: if `a` is 49 and `b` is 50, what should be the value of `c`?

Comment: @PythonSchlange You still didn't really explain, what you receive and what you want. Are you receiving ASCII encoded data (like the Serial Monitor does)? Or are you receiving simple integers? And what value in what type do you expect as output? The string "4950"? An integer with value 4950? Or are 49 and 50 the decimal values of the two bytes of an integer value?

Comment: a is in the example '49', which is 1 in ASCII, and b '50', which is 2. I expect c to be 12 in the end.

Comment: You mean something like `c = 10*(a-48) + b-48;` ?

Comment: @StarCat Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so after the lengthy requests for clarifications, it appears that
you are receiving a number in ASCII decimal (`"12"`) and want to parse
it into an integer.

You may use the `parseInt()` method of the serial object, like:

```cpp
int c = SerialBT.parseInt();
```

This can however make you program quite slow, as `parseInt()` uses a
timeout to know when to stop expecting more digits.

If you already have read the bytes, you can combine them with simple
arithmetics:

```cpp
int c = 10 * (a - '0') + (b - '0');
```

Note that `'0'` is the same as 48, only it makes more explicit the
intent of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now. But I recieve a decimal number, just for clearance.

Answer (score 1):

Use an AND mask to convert the character to a digit:

```c
int c = 10 * (a & 0x0F) + (b & 0x0F);
```

When ASCII was invented, the digits `0` to `9` were encoded in hexadecimal as `30` to `39` to enable easy conversion to/from digits and characters.

To convert a digit to ASCII, OR the byte with 0x30:

```c
byte digit = 5;
char character = digit | 0x30;
```

To convert a character to a digit, AND it with 0x0F:

```c
char character = '5';
byte digit = character & 0x0F;
```

These logical operators are faster and more efficient than mathematical operations + and -.

Comment: In what way are these operators faster and more efficient? A binary `&` and a subtraction both take a single clock cycle for an AVR. I.m.o this will only make your code less readable (make it less clear what it is actually doing).

Comment: Note also that the `byte()` conversion has no effect, as it is undone by the subsequent [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion). You can simply write `character & 0x0f`.

Comment: @starcat, Regarding readability: yes I agree, but those are the standard transforms since the inception of ASCII and are very well known so are recognised at a glance. Many people write their own macros or inline functions to make them more readable. Regarding speed and efficiency: the `&` and `|` circuits in the processor are simpler and use less power, and complete within a smaller fraction of the clock cycle. Regarding the AVR: it's but one of many that may use more clock cycles.

Comment: @edgar-bonet, it's for packing the byte into the assembly instruction along with the opcode, as many processors do.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, [ANDI - Logical AND with Immediate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V6Fr.png) from [AVR Instruction Set Manual, Page 36](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf)

Comment: Re “_speed and efficiency_”: I doubt you will save a mere picojoule by replacing a subtraction by a bitwise and. You must provide actual measurement data if you want to argue that the difference in energy consumption between `subi` and `andi` is at least measurable, let alone relevant in real life. Re “_packing the byte into the assembly instruction_”: this makes no sense. Semantically, `character & byte(0x0F)` means `int(character) & int(byte(0x0F))`, per the rules of the language. Practically, you get the same generated assembly whether you cast or not.

Comment: Packing the byte into the instruction is standard practice. For the AVR `ANDI` instruction, the immediate **K**onstant byte is split into [two nibbles labelled `KKKK`...`KKKK`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V6Fr.png).

Comment: What's your point? How is this relevant to the discussion? The same “packing” (called an “immediate” operand) applies to the subtraction instruction `subi`. And you get the same assembly instruction whether you use a cast to `byte` or not.

Comment: I just compiled a test using bitwise OR `|` for `uint_8` and another for `int` in VS for x86. It honoured the typecasts, i.e. `movzx eax,byte ptr [digit]` and `mov eax,dword ptr [int_digit]`, but this is not conclusive because it's a 32-bit processor, so it used a 32-bit `|` for both, which is still more efficient than using an adder or subtractor circuit. For the 8-bit AVR processor it should use the `ANDI` instruction. What compiler are you using that doesn't honour the typecasts?

Comment: And the power savings are important for extending battery life, for example.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, I just compiled the test in AVR gcc 9.2.0. It used `lds r24,digit`, `ori r24,lo8(48)` for the `byte` while it uses `lds r24,int_digit`, `lds r25,int_digit+1`, `ori r25,3` for the `int`. So it, too, honours the typecasts. What compiler are you using that doesn't honour the typecasts?

Comment: -1 for turning a perfectly good, 5 paragraph answer into a school book report.

Comment: Sorry @VE7JRO. It was in response to EdgarBonet's comments.

Comment: @VE7JRO, On reflection, I might revert to the previous version because I think StarCat and EdgarBonet were simply trolling. We'll see how it goes for now. I was going to add a section about logic gate efficiency as well... a thesis!

Comment: @tim - Why don't you add the max number of chars to your answer to make it even better!!! I think the limit is 30,000 chars per post (HINT: "per post"). Everyone on the planet knows that the longer the answer, the better :)

Comment: BTW @VE7JRO, if you thought it was a perfectly good answer why didn't you up-vote it before I added to it? :) And I have a Quartus synthesizer to hand to prove the point about efficiency of a 2-input OR gate versus a full-adder circuit. LOL

Comment: @tim - The Arduino Stack Exchange network only gives each user a limited number of votes per day (24 maybe?). I didn't think your answer was worth an up vote when you first posted it, so I didn't up vote it. You've been a member of SO - Stack Exchange for six and one half years, so the up vote / down vote process should not be a surprise to you.

Comment: @tim, Trolling? No, it was meant as a genuine comment. I didn’t (and still don’t) see the point of this kind of optimization as an answer to this particular question. It can be useful in other situations where a high level of optimization is essential. Just not here. I just don’t believe this is a useful answer.

Comment: I tried with both avr-g++ 5.4.0 (as shipped with Ubuntu 18.04) and avr-g++ 7.3.0 (from Arduino 1.8.13). Both ignore the typecast, as they should per the language rules (read about “C++ integral promotion”). Note that your test is flawed: not only are you changing the typecasts, but also the types and values of the data: the generated assembly obviously has to be different. Read my first comment: I just wrote that `character & byte(0x0f)` is equivalent to `character & 0x0f`. That's all there is to compare. PS: it looks like you compiled at optimization level 0. Nobody would ever do that.

Comment: Thank you @tim for another soulution, but StarCat's and Edgar Bonet's way is just easier. I don't need the faster soulution in this project as it won't give me any advantage. But anyway, thanks.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, I tried `int i1 = c1 & char(0x0f);` and `int i1 = c1 & char(0x0f0f);` Both gave `andi r24,15` so it honoured the typecast. I also tried `int i1 = c1 & int(0x0f);` and `int i1 = c1 & int(0x0f0f);` The former gave `andi r24,15` optimised because 15 fits in a byte; the latter gave `andi r24,15`, `andi r25,15`.

Comment: @PythonSchlange, thanks for the compliment. While it may not be necessary in your particular project, it's essential for battery powered products and low power products in general because it's easier on the power consumption. It's nothing new, `&` and `|` have been the efficient method for the last 60 years. The mathematical operators are a degradation of the original design intent of ASCII `30` to `39` hex.

Comment: @StarCat, OK you weren't trolling, and I did give you a genuine answer at the time. The OP didn't specify what level of optimisation they wanted, so I simply gave the 60-year-old industry standard method. However, due to compiler optimisations, it's possible to remove the typecasts to make it more readable.

Comment: Re “_industry standard method_”: it was indeed standard in the times when you would do it with dedicated circuitry. If you believe it is still “industry standard” when done today, on a contemporary CPU, please provide some reference. Otherwise I would say it's no more than [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: Re “_it's essential for battery powered products_”: Essential? Really? You are visibly not afraid of hyperboles... I performed some [actual measurements](https://gist.github.com/edgar-bonet/7afbf8b1df02534ac142cf84bb12e87a) to see the difference. I invite you to take a look. Spoiler: its far from “essential”.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, What is the value of the [pull-up resistor inside your Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins) on PD2 for `SUBI`? And what is the the value your pull-down resistor on PD2 for `ANDI`? What is the energy consumption of this internal pull-up resistor when shorted to ground via PD2 for the `ANDI` test?

Comment: @EdgarBonet, Rather than being "somewhat surprising", it's highly predictable and obvious to a professional design engineer and hobbyist alike. Although you 'concluded' that a 1% difference (in favour of `SUBI`) was negligible, you need to consider the bigger picture of the real world. How many ASCII `30` to `39`characters are sent across the internet and transposed to/from `0` to `9`? What is the energy consumption of that multitude? A 1% fraction of a [huge number](https://www.google.com/search?q=internet+energy+consumption) is still a lot of energy.

Comment: The internal (and only) pull-up is about 30 kΩ. There is no pull-down. Note that, for the `andi` test, I disconnected PD2 before making the measurement in order to not be affected by the pull-up current. Your remark about the energy consumption of the whole Internet is completely out of topic in this Arduino-centric site.

Comment: Some (at least) of the current difference looks like that from the internal pull-up resistor left shorted to ground via PD2 throughout the `ANDI` test. Regarding this site's context, it's completely on-topic to highlight energy reduction especially as it relates to IoT for which Arduinos are used extensively. Besides, you broadened the topic by mentioning "real world applications" on your GitHub link. The principle of using `|` and `&`  were sound in 1960 and remain sound to this day - even more so with today's scale of usage.

Comment: 1. As I already said, the internal pull-up was disconnected from ground while I was measuring the consumption. 2. I do not intend to broaden the context. IoT, microcontrollers, and even Arduinos are seen in real world applications. 3. I do not dispute that `&` is a sound option. I dispute that it is “essential” (your word) to choose it over a subtraction. 4. This discussion has drifted way too far. [Followup on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63862117).

Comment: @VE7JRO, I've reverted to the "perfectly good answer". Could you un-down-vote it please?

Comment: @tim - No problemo :)  Now we just need a moderator to move these comments to chat where they belong. The SE robot generates a "flag" for the mod's at 20 comments, yet we are now up to 32 comments.